# Firefox browser works badly with multimedia, Fedora 22

Tags: fedora, audio, firefox, multimedia

At first, a short pre-history:
After unsuccessful upgrade with fedup from fedora 20 to 22, I reinstalled fedora 22 with live usb. I had partitions for /, /boot, /usr and /home, so I rewrited only /boot and /. I reinstalled only some apps and firefox among them.
And now strange things happen:
Some videos in browser (non-youtube) are broken, they are shown as chaotic lines on page. Also, if youtube player is opened (even, if paused), all another sounds of system are disabled. If I close page with youtube, sounds works well. I can even run vlc and audio player together and they are working.
So, what's wrong? What I should do? (audio system - pulse)